# Unable to SSH into server, FTP is possible

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running the Ubuntu 18.04 Linux dist on a VPS. I am unable to connect to it via SSH, and pinging the SSH port as well as attempting to connect result in a timeout.

**Here's what I know:**

- Pinging port 21 (edit: more formally, opening a TCP connection to port 21) for FTP *does work* and connecting via FTP is possible
- I have a docker panel running that is loading (but requesting info on individual containers returns a 504 timeout)
- I have a website (see https://status.mineplex.club) that is running, and making API requests from within the server successfully.
- ufw is disabled
- There is a VNC console given by my Cloud-VPS provider that allows for me to connect to the server, so I am able to access it internally and run commands.
- I did a port scan and it says port 22, 80, 443 and 8080 are all working. So why do I time out when I try to open a TCP connection to port 22, or connect to the server via SSH?
- I was able to curl https://www.website.com from within the server successfully

I'm not very knowledgable in Linux or networking. There is a solid chance there is a "standard" on the Unix StackExchange when it comes to troubleshooting, but I'm not sure what logs would be helpful, so feel free to ask away.

Maybe an sshd issue?
png)

Comment: You should try from a local linux box `ssh -v your_host`. This will print many valuable information.

Comment: The screenshots show failure to connect to either port 21 or port 22. That's at odds with your question statements #1 and #6.

Comment: In your first image, the `nc -vz` command to VPS's port 21 results in a `Connection refused` error: that means *something that claims to be your VPS* is responding with a "no, I will not accept this connection". Another `nc -vz` to port 22 results in a `Connection timed out`: i.e. no answer whatsoever was received. That typically means a firewall or something similar on the way decided to discard either the `nc`'s initial connection package, or the returning response from the VPS. Check the Cloud-VPS provider's settings: perhaps there are settings for an external firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, SSH (or the SSH port) was blocked from the network I was trying to use it from. It was an educational building, but I didn't figure they'd go so far as to block something like this.

Immediately, when I got to my home network I was able to SSH in. Sorry for the trouble, this was a stupid issue on my end.